# Not able to open Paradox database using Paradox data Editor

Tags: paradox

I have a .db Paradox file. When I try to open it using Paradox data editor Version 2.5.1.0, I get the following error "Network Initialization Failed. Permission deneid.
File: C:\Program Files (x86)\PDE\PDOXUSRS.Net
Directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\PDE." Not able to Proceed. Please help...

Thanks,
Sri.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may not be a complete answer, but you need both read and write access to the PDoxUsrs.net file. Folders under C:\Program Files (x86) are typically write protected.

Try to use the BDE administration/config utility to change the location of the "NET DIR" (under Configuration tab, in the "Configuration|Drivers|Native|Paradox" tree node) to a folder that you have full rights to.

Comment: I have the same problem but I have no PDoxUsrs.net file. How do I get one? I tried the BDE Administration tool but that did not create PDoxUsrs.net for me.

Comment: The PdoxUsrs.net file is typically auto-created after you start your BDE aware application. Maybe there's something wrong with the "NET DIR" path?

Answer (score 0):

OK Guys, do as Tor Langlo has instructed above viz:

Copy the PDOXUSERS.NET file to another (preferably root - easy to find) location away from your C root system drive. You could put it on a USB drive if you only have one hard drive on your system.
You can leave the original file where it was if you wish.

Open the executable, go to View>BDE Properties>Session 
and in the Network Control File Directory type or select the new path to your moved file and check OK to exit.

Start the program and find your database you wish to open. 
You should find that it opens correctly now.
Good Luck.